# koa-static going to next middleware

Tags: node.js, koa, koa2

I have a koa 2 server.

The following code are my middlewares:

```
// parse body
app.use( bodyParser() )

// serve static
app.use( serve( path.join(__dirname, '/public') ) )

// routes
app.use( routes )

// error middleware
app.use( async ctx => ctx.throw(500) )
```

Everything works well but my problem is that when I go to *localhost:8000*, where my server lives, in the console I see the following error:

> InternalServerError: Internal Server Error
>         at Object.throw (/Users/work/Desktop/server/node_modules/koa/lib/context.js:91:23)

I'm suspecting that after static, the app is going to the next middleware, which is the error middleware.

PS. I'm using `app.use( async ctx => ctx.throw(500) )`, to call `next()` if I'm getting errors on the other routes.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you still have the issue if you comment out the error middleware?

Comment: no, but i need that

Comment: Ok, just making sure that's where the issue was coming from. Could you share your `routes` code?

Comment: For future readers, another approach without using another package on [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78128628)

Answer (score 0):

> I'm suspecting that after static, the app is going to the next
>   middleware, which is the error middleware.

`koa-static` transfers control to the next middleware by design.
Your `routes` middleware also `await` to the next middleware.
So you get an error.

> Does anyone know how to fix this?

It's hard to say what you are going to achieve in the first place.
Setting 500 manually is probably a wrong idea. There should be 404 like:

```
// 404 middleware
app.use(async ({response}, next) => {
  if (!this.body) {
    response.status = 404
    response.body = "Not Found" // or use template   
  }
  await next() // send control flow back (upstream)
})
```

For SPA (without SSR) you probably want this catch-all route to send APP layout instead. And move that `404` middleware to the beginning of the file (where it will take control on the second "bubbling" phase.

Make sure you checked [this](https://github.com/koajs/koa/blob/master/docs/guide.md)

Comment: "koa-static transfers control to the next middleware by design." To answer the question he actually asked, and what Google lead me to, is there any way to avoid transferring control to the next middleware? It seems counter-productive to run all the middleware for static files. I'm looking to serve css and js files, and no middleware would ever have the need to modify, interrupt or in any way control that specific part.

Comment: There's only a "defer" option to flip the order of middlewares. No option to skip the middleware stack, unfortunately. Couldn't believe myself, when I first saw this. I agree it sucks, someone needs to raise an issue probably.

Answer (score 0):

use like, you add a middleware to handle your custom error properly...

```
    // serve static
app.use(serve(path.join(__dirname, '/public')))
// error middleware
app.use(async(ctx, next) => {
    try {
        await next();
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message);
        ctx.body = e.message
    } finally {}
})
// routes
app.use(router.routes()).use(router.allowedMethods());

router.get('/a', ctx => {
    try {
        ctx.body = "sadsa"
    } catch (e) {
        ctx.body = e
        console.log(e);
    } finally {}
});
app.use(ctx => ctx.throw(500))
app.listen(7000)
```

Comment: would you mind explaining what you are doing differently from the OP and why.  There is always a teaching moment and will help others that encounter this problem that may be subtly different.