# Why can't I serve static files from a Koa router?

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa, koa-router, koa-static

Why in the following case does `koa-static` fail to work with `koa-router`?

```
const Koa = require("koa")
const serve = require("koa-static")
const Router = require("koa-router")

const app = new Koa()
const router = new Router()

// fails with 404... why?
router.use(serve("public"))

// // this, on the other hand, works
// app.use(serve("public"))

app.use(router.middleware())
app.listen(8080)

// browse to "http://localhost:8080/testfile.txt"
```

#### I made this GitHub repo to demo the issue: [koa-router-static-issue](https://github.com/chase-moskal/koa-router-static-issue)

Comment: try add "./"  -> router.use(serve("./dist/clientside"))

Comment: @VadimHulevich — unfortunately I have found that adding the `./` prefix has no affect

Comment: Can you display your 404 error ?

Comment: @Sparw — the browser displays the text `Not Found` — also, I've created this [git repo](https://github.com/chase-moskal/koa-router-static-issue) as a simple sandbox to demonstrate the issue

Comment: For future readers, another approach without using another package on [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78128628)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is essentially how we have stuff configured in our app.

It uses `koa-mount` to mount the static file server at a particular root URL. If your static file URLs overlap the namespace of your routes, the static files win.

```
const Koa    = require('koa')
const Router = require('koa-router')
const serve  = require('koa-static')
const mount  = require('koa-mount')

const app    = new Koa()
const router = new Router()

router.get('/public/foobar.txt', (ctx,next) => {

  ctx.body   = "Ta-Da!"
  ctx.status = 200

  return;
})

app.use( mount( '/public', serve('./public') ) ) ;
app.use( router.middleware())

app.listen( 8080 ) ;
```

Comment: Nicholas, that's fine for static paths but the benefits of the router allow for dynamic route parameters. For example, consider a multi-tenant app -/public/:tenant/:site/:slug* - because the static is mounted to the app, and not router middleware, you can't use dynamic paths. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to wrap the static folder in a way that it can serve as a fallback for router...

```
const router = Router();
router.get('/', (ctx) => { ctx.body = 'Hello World!' });
app.use(serve('/tmp'));
app.use(router.routes());
```

In that example going to `/` would take you to helloWorld, and fallback to any files in `/tmp/`

source: https://github.com/ZijianHe/koa-router/issues/446