# How can I send a React app from a Koa.js server?

Tags: reactjs, koa

I have React app. I have `bundle.js` and `index.html` with scripts and a root element. How I can send it from the server?

I have a Koa.js server

```
const Koa = require('koa');
const app = new Koa();

app.use(async ctx => {
  ctx.body = 'Hello World';
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Can I send `index.html` as a static file, or does react have another way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Koa.js - serving static files and REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32721311/koa-js-serving-static-files-and-rest-api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy. You need to install [koa-static](https://github.com/koajs/static). Also have a folder for your static files, for example `public`, you need to have your reactjs app build there. Then add koa-static middleware to your server, here's a gist of it:

```
const Koa = require('koa')
const serve = require('koa-static')

const app = new Koa();
app.use(serve(__dirname + '/public'))

app.listen(3000)
```