# How can I serve a static file using Koa?

Tags: node.js, server, mount, koa, serve

I want to implement universal links in my project and I need to serve a json via Koa, which is a static file named **apple-app-site-association**.

My file is located in **/assets/apple-app-site-association/apple-app-site-association** folder.

My concern is that I cannot access this https://myprojectlink/apple-app-site-association.

What I have at this moment:

```
const path = require("path");
const Koa = require("koa");
const mount = require("koa-mount");
const serve = require("koa-better-serve");

app.use(mount("/apple-app-site-association", serve(path.resolve(__dirname,"../../../assets/apple-app-site-association/apple-app-site-association"))));
```

I get Not Found, it seems like I cannot serve it in the right way.

What can I do?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: For future readers, another approach without using another package on [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78128628)

Answer (score 11):

The [koa-static](https://github.com/koajs/static) module is what you are looking for. You can use this to serve a single file or entire directory to a given path. Here are a couple of examples that should help:

## Serving Files With `koa-static`

To serve files just pass the `koa-static` middleware to the koa's middleware stack with `app.use()`.

#### Serve an Entire Directory

Here we are serving the entire `/static` directory

```js
const Koa = require('koa')
const serve = require('koa-static')
const path = require('path')

const app = new Koa()
app.use(serve(path.join(__dirname, '/static')))

app.listen(3000)
```

#### Serve a Single File

Here we are serving a single file, for example, the `data.json` file inside of the `/static` directory

```js
const Koa = require('koa')
const serve = require('koa-static')
const path = require('path')

const app = new Koa()
app.use(serve(path.join(__dirname, '/static/data.json')))

app.listen(3000)
```

#### Serve Directory or File on a Given Path

Use [koa-mount](https://github.com/koajs/mount) to mount [koa-static](https://github.com/koajs/static) to a given path. For example, here we mount the entire `/static` directory to be served on the `/public` path

```js
const Koa = require('koa')
const serve = require('koa-static')
const mount = require('koa-mount')
const path = require('path')

const app = new Koa()
app.use(mount('/public ',serve(path.join(__dirname, '/static'))))

app.listen(3000)
```

Answer (score 0):

`serve` (koa-better-serve), like most static server middlewares for Node frameworks, takes a path to a directory, not a path to a single file. You can also get rid of the `mount()` call, `koa-mount` is for mounting other Koa apps as middleware.

`app.use(serve(path.resolve(__dirname,"../../../assets/apple-app-site-association/")));`

Answer (score 0):

The official method for static-file serving is https://www.npmjs.com/package/koa-static, you can see the documentation there.